# Carriage Return Detecting as Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, 7-bit

I am using this [SMS Counter PHP Class Library](https://github.com/acpmasquerade/sms-counter-php) for one of my project.

```
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$scounter = SMSCounter::count(utf8_urldecode($msg));
```

When I use `Carriage Return` or `Enter` key in the `msg` text area, it is detecting as Unicode and hence my message counting goes for a toss. As per the class, it counts the message as Unicode of / 67 chars and counts 4 times.

I googled since yesterday for a solution and I could not understand, how could I stop the lib class to consider `Carriage Return` or `Enter` key as GSM_7bit instead of Unicode.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add chr(13) to your 7Bit map function, it will detect as GSM 7Bit.

```
public static function int_gsm_7bit_map(){
    return array(10,13,32.........
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked as intended, thanks so much, I was literally going mad on this. Upvoted and accepted. Thanks again